# RecyclerView is not occupying full height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a simple layout, but I found that `RecyclerView` is unable to occupy full height, but it wraps the height of its contents instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gridList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/bg_list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The structure is super simple. What did I miss to let the `RecyclerView` fills up the whole screen?

Comment: can you show us the image???

Answer (score 0):

Added layout should fill the screen height. If I use your layout wihout background, I am able to see correct output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gridList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem seems at line `android:background="@mipmap/bg_list"`. Check into `bg_list` which may affecting height.